# Error Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'. when using Map.fromIterable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert a `List` to a `Map<int, Widget>` for the children of a `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl`. I tried using `Map.fromIterable` but I get an error...

Here's my code:

```dart
final List<String> tabValues = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
          groupValue: selectedTab,
          onValueChanged: _onTabChange,
          children: Map.fromIterable(
            tabValues,
            value: (element) => _tabContent(element),
          ),
        )

Widget _tabContent(String text) {
  return Text(text);
}
```

Getting an error:

> Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.

Comment: You are missing the `key` mapping

Comment: @smac89 Can u show me a sample please?

Comment: In your `Map<int, Widget>`, is the `int` supposed to be the index of the widget?

Comment: @smac89 yes. so outcome should be `{0: Text('first), 1: Text('second'), 2: Text('third)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Map.fromIterable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html) function expects both `key`, and `value` mapping functions.

You need to either supply both of these or none, which if you choose the later, means you will get a `Map<T, T>` where the key and value functions are replaced with the identity function.

---

In your case, I would do something like this:

```dart
children: tabValues.asMap().map((index, tabValue) => MapEntry(index, _tabContent(tabValue)))
```

The `key` which should be the index of the widget is created when we did `tabValues.asMap()`, so now all we need is to call `.map` to convert the `tabValue` to a widget.